# Web Payment API/Services that can be easily integrated with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, payment-gateway

What are some of the popular web payment API/services that can be easily integrated with ruby on rails framework? I have tried using PayPal the standard version and it was not too flexibler. I have never tried the pro version. Can you guys suggest other alternatives out there that are easy to use, secure, not too hefty on the commission as well and have **subscription/recurring** payment functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Stripe. You can see nice short screencast by Ryan Bates here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe

There are also two other options with screent cast, namely PayPal http://railscasts.com/episodes/141-paypal-basics 
and Active Merchant http://railscasts.com/episodes/144-active-merchant-basics

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.net has an API with sample code for Ruby and several other languages.  No direct rails plugin, but I am sure it can be easily incorporated.  I used the PHP version and incorporated it in under an hour.  It has all the functions that you mentioned in your post.